# Files with "sh" extension on windows

Tags: windows

Our Apache web server works in a Linux environment.
The cgi executables are called via a sh file (for example /cgi-bin/iwsblogin.sh).
The call "/cgi-bin/iwsblogin.sh" is in an html file.

Now I want to make a development and testing environment for this web server on windows.

I do not want to change the calls in the html files from "iwsblogin.sh" to "iwsblogin.bat" just for testing purposes.

Is there a way to configure windows in such a way, that files with the extension ".sh" are treated as executables the same way as ".bat" and ".exe" files?

The contents of this .sh file is for example:
- ms dos commands for setting some environment variables.
- Path of an exe file which should be called.

I know that there exist similar questions on stackoverflow where user suggest using cygwin, but this is NOT an option for me!

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this.

1. If the .sh file works when you rename it to .bat, you can use "run as" and select C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe as default program
2. Use a sh emulator. For example, [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) includes one or you can use [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) (possibly the same source?).

I know you don't want to use cygwin, but why not? Please explain why this isn't an option. It is hard to look for an answer if we don't know why regular answers won't work.